# Error: class does not contain a definition and no extension method

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, extension-methods

In my code below, it is supposed to do the following tasks:

Prompt the user for values for each Order. Do not allow duplicate order numbers; force the user to reenter the order when a duplicate order number is entered. When five valid orders have been entered, display them all, plus a total of all orders.

The problem is that there are errors in it. I tried to solve the errors by myself but I can't fix it. I've been stuck in these errors for many hours. And another thing, I can't really understand why does it displays that OrderDemo does not contain a definition for Total, OrderNumber, Customer and Quantity. Any help given would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
using System;

class OrderDemo
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        OrderDemo[] order = new OrderDemo[5];
        int x, y;
        double grandTotal = 0;
        bool goodNum;
        for (x = 0; x < order.Length; ++x)
        {
            order[x] = new Order(); //OrderDemo.Order does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
            Console.Write("Enter order number");
            order[x].OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            goodNum = true;
            for (y = 0; y < x; ++y)
            {
                if (order[x].Equals(order[y]))
                    goodNum = false;
            }
            while (!goodNum)
            {
                Console.Write("sorry, the order number " + order[x].OrderNumber + "is a duplicate. " + "\nPlease reenter: ");
                order[x].OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//OrderDemo does not contain a definition for OrderNumber and no extension..
                goodNum = true;
                for (y = 0; y > x; ++y)
                {
                    if (order[x].Equals(order[y]))
                        goodNum = false;
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Enter customer name");
            order[x].Customer = Console.ReadLine();//OrderDemo does not contain a definition for Customer and no extension..
            Console.Write("Enter Quantity");
            order[x].Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//OrderDemo does not contain a definition for Quantity and no extension..
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSummary\n");
        for (x = 0; x < order.Length; ++x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(order[x].ToString());
            grandTotal += order[x].Total; //OrderDemo does not contain a definition for Total and no extension..
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" Total for all orders is" + grandTotal.ToString("c"));

    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int orderNum;
        public string cusName;
        public int quantity;
        public double total;
        public const double ItemPrice = 19.95;

        public Order(int ordNum, string cusName, int numOrdered)
        {
            OrderNum = ordNum;
            Customer = cusName;
            Quantity = numOrdered;
        }

        public int OrderNum
        {
            get { return orderNum; }
            set { orderNum = value; }
        }
        public string Customer
        {
            get { return cusName; }
            set { cusName = value; }
        }
        public int Quantity
        {
            get
            {
                return quantity;
            }
            set
            {
                quantity = value;
                total = quantity * ItemPrice;
            }
        }
        public double Total
        {
            get
            {
                return total;
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("Order " + OrderNum + " " + Customer + " " + Quantity +
                " @Php" + ItemPrice.ToString("0.00") + " each. " + "The total is Php" + Total.ToString("0.00"));
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object e)
        {
            bool equal;
            Order temp = (Order)e;
            if (OrderNum == temp.OrderNum)
                equal = true;
            else
                equal = false;
            return equal;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return OrderNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `order[x] = new Order();` does not work because `order` is a `OrderDemo[]` not a `Order[]`. You also need a parameterless constructor in `Order` if you've provided one with parameters yourself. Otherwise you cannot use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# provides a default constructor for you, **as long as you don't define other constructors which accept parameters**. Because you have this:

```
public Order(int ordNum, string cusName, int numOrdered)
{
    OrderNum = ordNum;
    Customer = cusName;
    Quantity = numOrdered;
}
```

The default constructor isn't generated. You need to add this:

```
public Order() { }
```

...if you want to create objects without passing parameters to it.

Also, as SLaks has pointed out, you have declared your array incorrectly:

```
OrderDemo[] order = new OrderDemo[5];
```

Should be this instead:

```
var order = new Order[5]; // or Order[] order = new Order[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared your array as containing `OrderDemo` objects.
As the error clearly states, `OrderDemo` doesn't have any properties.

You probably mean `Order`, which is a different class.